# How to override scroll functions in a window?

Tags: javascript, scroll

How do you override scroll functions of a browser in JavaScript?

Functions which I was able to find are `scroll`, `scrollBy` and `scrollTo` (from the `window` object).
But, if I try to override them using the standard procedure, like any other function, for example, by executing the following code `window.scroll = function(parameter){}` it does not have any effect on the browser.
So, if I try to scroll the page after executing the above code (for all 3 methods), the window still scrolls.

Are there any other functions which browser uses to scroll? If so, which function should I override to get a custom scrolling behaviour?

I am using Google Chrome (latest version), of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `window.scroll`, `window.scrollTo` and `window.scrollBy` methods do not refer to the native scrolling functionality. They are used to scroll to specific locations on the webpage. If you want to implement a completly custom scrolling functionality/behaviour you need to listen to the `wheel` event, prevent the default and define your custom behaviour.

##### Note: changed scroll to wheel event as comment mentioned error

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // now define custom functionality
}, { passive: false });
```

Instead of window you can also apply it to any other element on the page that has a scrollbar and therefore being scrollable.

Futhermore the wheel event has values for deltaX and deltaY so you can see how much would have been scrolled since the last scroll and you can use the properties x and y to see how much had been scrolled since the beginning.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` doesn't prevent the scrolling from happening, but it does give you an opportunity to undo the scroll that has happened.

Comment: @LonnieBest Thanks for that hint, I changed the event and tested again. The snippet now does prevent scroll from happening.

Comment: @LonnieBest You might need to change window to the actual scrollable element. window   only served as an example. Or change it to document, that works as well.

Comment: Yeah, now it works. Good job.

Comment: This fixes the issue for scrolling by a mouse wheel, but not for scrolling by the keyboard page down or up and arrow keys nor by mouse click on the scrollbar. However, this gave me a very good starting point. I overrode ```keydown``` event for the keyboard, now, only thing what remains is to solve the case when scrolling is performed by click on the scrollbar. But I will probably figure out this as well. In any case, thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript, I'm not sure how to completely prevent the scroll, but you can scroll to a particular location right after they try to scroll, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

```html
<h1>Try to Scroll</h1>
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Notice that despite my attempts to be thorough, you can still see a little scrolling happen before `window.scrollTo(0,0);` undoes it.

**CSS**

If all you're trying to do is prevent scrolling, you can use `overflow: hidden` with CSS:

```css
html,body { overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<h1>Try to Scroll</h1>
<ol>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Palladium02's answer now works with javascript exclusively. He uses the `wheel` event instead of `scroll`. Pretty cool.